# Transfer private maven repository to AWS CodeArtifact

Tags: maven, artifactory, transfer, artifacts, aws-codeartifact

How can I transfer a private Maven repository (Artifactory) to AWS CodeArtifact?
Are there any tools to handle this or specific maven commands?

I have searched many times to find a solution, but I did not found the correct answer that I am looking for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with such tools. You will probably need to write a script to download and upload all Maven artifact files. If I may ask - what is the reason for this transfer?

Comment: We are considering moving from a self-hosted solution to a hosted solution. To hand over the maintenance and care.

Comment: So why not JFrog's hosted solution? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Cloud
See also: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Transfer+Artifactory+Configuration+and+Files+to+JFrog+Cloud

Comment: Marco, I have encountered the same task and just wonder have you found a solution?